# Windows Store App - XAML - Bind two values for Height Property

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps

I want to bind the height of a control the sum of two other heights, so the UI looks nice various screen sizes.

```
<GridView
    AutomationProperties.AutomationId="ItemDetails"
    ItemsSource="{Binding data}"
    IsSwipeEnabled="False"
    SelectionMode="None" Height="{Binding Height, (ElementName=item - ElementName=itemTitle)}" >
    <GridView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <dll:TaskItemControl/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridView.ItemTemplate>
</GridView>
```

The above XAML is invalid, but it demonstrates what I want to do. I have two elements, `item` and `itemTitle`. `item` is a `ScrollView` that gets set to the height of the screen and I want the `GridView` to be the same height as the `ScrollView` minus the height of the `itemTitle`.

Is there a way to do this in XAML?

Note: The reasons for doing this are beyond the scope of this question. So please don't comment about restricting the height of a control within a `ScrollView`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be easily done in code behind by subscribing the `SizeChanged` events of the two elements and update the `Height` of the `GridView` whenever the handlers are called.

But you want a pure XAML solution, and this is where [Behaviors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xaml.interactivity.ibehavior.aspx) come into play.

**Use a Behavior**.

First you need to add Blend SDK reference to your project.
[image]

Then you need to create a new class that implements `IBehavior`. This class needs three `dependency properties` just to reference the `GridView`, the `item` and the `itemTitle`. So you can subscribe to their `SizeChanged` events and calulate the `Height` accordingly.

I choose to attach this behavior to a top level `Panel` (most likely your **LayoutRoot** `Grid`) because I want to ensure that all the elements under it are rendered properly inside its `Loaded` event handler.

The **full Behavior class** would look something like this -

```
public class HeightBehavior : DependencyObject, IBehavior
{
    public GridView GridView
    {
        get { return (GridView)GetValue(GridViewProperty); }
        set { SetValue(GridViewProperty, value); }
    }

public static readonly DependencyProperty GridViewProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("GridView", typeof(GridView), typeof(HeightBehavior), new PropertyMetadata(null));

public FrameworkElement FirstItem
{
    get { return (FrameworkElement)GetValue(FirstItemProperty); }
    set { SetValue(FirstItemProperty, value); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty FirstItemProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("FirstItem", typeof(FrameworkElement), typeof(HeightBehavior), new PropertyMetadata(null));

public FrameworkElement SecondItem
{
    get { return (FrameworkElement)GetValue(SecondItemProperty); }
    set { SetValue(SecondItemProperty, value); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty SecondItemProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("SecondItem", typeof(FrameworkElement), typeof(HeightBehavior), new PropertyMetadata(null));

public DependencyObject AssociatedObject { get; set; }

public void Attach(DependencyObject associatedObject)
{
    this.AssociatedObject = associatedObject;

    var control = (Panel)this.AssociatedObject;
    control.Loaded += AssociatedObject_Loaded;
}

private void AssociatedObject_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    this.FirstItem.SizeChanged += FirstItem_SizeChanged;
    this.SecondItem.SizeChanged += SecondItem_SizeChanged;

    // force to re-calculate the Height
    this.FirstItem.Width += 0.5;
}

private void FirstItem_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
{
    this.SetAssociatedObjectsHeight();
}

private void SecondItem_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
{
    this.SetAssociatedObjectsHeight();
}

private void SetAssociatedObjectsHeight()
{
    this.GridView.Height = this.FirstItem.ActualHeight - this.SecondItem.ActualHeight;
}

public void Detach()
{
    this.FirstItem.SizeChanged -= FirstItem_SizeChanged;
    this.SecondItem.SizeChanged -= SecondItem_SizeChanged;

    var control = (Panel)this.AssociatedObject;
    control.Loaded -= AssociatedObject_Loaded;
}
```

}

Then in my XAML, I attach it to my top level `Grid`, like this.

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
        <Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <local:HeightBehavior GridView="{Binding ElementName=itemGridView}" FirstItem="{Binding ElementName=item}" SecondItem="{Binding ElementName=itemTitle}"/>
        </Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
```

Hope this helps.